# Parsing values as they appear in an excel sheet using Apache POI library

Tags: android, excel, parsing, apache-poi

I have problem in parsing excel sheet using poi lib.
where all the string value are correct but phone gets converted into decimal format like if phone number is **9876543210** after parsing it i'm getting **9.876543210E10**
How to get proper phone number while parsing.
my code is-

```
while(cellIter.hasNext()){

                        HSSFCell myCell = (HSSFCell) cellIter.next();
                        String cellValue = "";

                        // Check for cell Type
                        if(myCell.getCellType() == HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_STRING){
                            cellValue = myCell.getStringCellValue();
                        }
                        else if(myCell.getCellType() == HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC){
                            System.out.println("cell type -- number"+myCell.getNumericCellValue());
                            cellValue =new Double( (myCell.getNumericCellValue()))+"";
                        }
}
```

Comment: You should read as StringCellValue. That big number can't be read in as an Integer.

Comment: but it always enters in else part as cell type is HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING)` to set type of column before read.

Like

```
else if(myCell.getCellType() == HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC){
    // Set type as String
    myCell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
    // And read as String
    String numberAsString = myCell.getStringCellValue();

    System.out.println("cell type -- number"+numberAsString);

    try {
        cellValue = Double.parseDouble(numberAsString);
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        cellValue = 0; // Handle unexpected values
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you used the whole code which I posted? What is output for `numberAsString` ?

Comment: Yes its working actually instead of getting value in string variable i was accessing it directly so couldn't get.

Comment: Ok. You can also use `BigInteger cellValue = new BigInteger(numberAsString);` at place of using Double, if numbers are too long.. :)

Comment: i'm using it as string only.there is no issue now..thanks for solving my problem :)

Answer (score 3):

You can also use a generalized solution to get your excel data as is and in the same format as you see in the excel.

`apache-poi` provides for [`DataFormatter`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ibM5W.png) class as utility to leverage the format of the content *as it appears* on the excel. You can choose custom formats too, a simple example would be (cell is reference to your `XSSFCell` object):

**Excel sheet looks like:**

[image]

**Code:**

```
System.out.println(new DataFormatter().formatCellValue(cell));
```

The above line would print:

```
50%
$ 1,200
12/21/14
9886605446
```

Whereas your normal print would interpret it differently:

```
0.5
1200.0
21-Dec-2014
9.886605446E9
```